# 10 hours worth of work for my first project, only to have it disappear without an answer..yet

Tags: animation, texturing

As the title says, 10 hours I spent today working on scene animation for Realistic Mountains, a tutorial I found on youtube. An hour of a video was 10 hours of work for me, since it was the first time I was really using the website. When it came to wanting to make it into video format, I looked up to do so and so then click animation. Once I did, an error popped up telling me something didn't fit, then everything went pink. I then looked up that it was missing textures, but when trying to find them it keeps saying it can't even though they're very much right there. I was extremely upset realizing I may not get something I was extremely proud of and ready to show people, it was fairly impressive for somebody's first time. Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your problem so that is easier for people to try and help?

Comment: Hi. It would be more productive to tell us about the actual problem in more detail then about your emotions. If you are only missing texture files, you can always go to File > External Data > Find Missing Files. I am hesitating to put this into an answer because I am not sure I understand the problem correctly from the description.

Comment: As said I've already tried that, if you were to have really read through it wasn't just about my emotions but I will sum it up much shorter if that helps: I have already tried doing that it was the first thing I tried. However it tells me it cannot find those files, even though they haven't been moved or anything like that. It appears that clicking Animation did nothing but glitch out my project for some reason, turning everything pink. Regardless of me trying to do as Martin Z Said, it still tells me it can't find it. It's extremely confusing to figure out why

Comment: So, does it only appear pink when you try to animate it? Or does the same effect appear when you do a preview render? (shift+z)

Comment: There isn't any information about the problem itself in the question generally. What does it mean you "cllicked animation"? Blender's UI is complex and has multiple contexts which makes this description vague. *error popped up telling me something didn't fit* What didn't fit? What error did tell you exactly? How did it look and where it was, could you show a screenshot please or at least more thorough description? Did you reload the project before error showed up? Did you save the project? If everything is pink Blender can't find textures, they aren't in the same location it searches them for

Comment: Enlightenment about saving your work now and then to MULTIPLE projects INCLUDING the textures (no matter it costs space)! That "find the missing files" option is folder-dependent so if You know FOR SURE that You did NOT delete any textures than try to run it on a whole drive...

Comment: There is actually another case where the famous "pink texture" appears. If you are using cycles with GPU rendering, then iirc there is a fairly low maximum number of textures and beyond that some textures will appear pink. Is it possible is what the error was saying? (I've never actually encountered this myself, so I'm not sure if there's a warning or not). Have you tried switching to CPU rendering?

Comment: If you didn't change anything for sure try to pack the file by using **File->External Data->Pack All Into .blend**

if this file runs on other computers and works perfectly, then the problem is local, try collecting all the texture on one folder and reallocate them manually.

Comment: @gandalf3: I believe "Cuda out of memory" will show-up in cause U described.